# Ex. 2.1 K&R 2nd edition: How can I calculate the variables?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming. I referred to power function in chapter 1 and modified it to be power_sum function. My calculation is to insert value of bits in "show_val()" to show range of each variable. The problem is in the main when I want to insert a value into show_val. Please guide me how to solve this. Thank you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int power_sum(int base, int n);
void show_val(int power);

int main() {
  unsigned char vc = show_val(8);
  /* I try to show range of unsigned char here, but because show_val 
 is a void function, so it becomes error.*/
}

/* power_sum: raise base to n-th power and sum up; n => 0 */
int power_sum(int base, int n) {
  int i, p, sum;

  p = 1;
  sum = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    p = p * base;
    sum = sum + p;
  }
  sum = sum - 2;
  return sum;
}

/* show_val: to show value of each variable */
void show_val(int pw) {
  int n;
  int i;
  n = power_sum(2, pw);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) /* to display increments of a value ten times */ {
    printf("%d\n", ++n);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Change to `int show_val (int pw) {.....; return n;}` ?

Comment: Like you said, show_val doesn't return anything (it is a void function) so you can't assign the result to an unsigned char. What is it you need to return from show_val?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I got this error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: This is the question I need to do Ex 2.1: Write a program to determine the ranges of char, short, int and long variables,
   both signed and unsigned, by printing appropriate value from standard headers and by direct computation.
   Harder if you compute them: determine the ranges of the various floating-point types.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign void function `void show_val(int pw)` (a function that returns nothing) to `unsigned char vc` variable. If you want to return value from show_val function change: `int show_val(int pw)` and return something.
Otherwise, if you don't want to return anything, you can just call function in main:

```
int main()
{
    show_val(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unsigned char vc = show_val(8);

Let us break the above piece of code into LHS and RHS.

LHS :
Its a variable expecting a character to be inputed.

Now what is being done in RHS

RHS:
You have given show_val(8)

Which is a mistake

Why?
Because if you see you show_val declaration:
void show_val(int)
You are returning a void i.e nothing.
And trying to equate with char on LHS.

So, the compiler will definitely throw an error.

There are more changes to be made,
1st edit this part correctly in the question if you are clear and then we can look upon the other changes.